Integral of $\bar{z}$ along straight lines
I'm supposed to evaluate the integral:
\begin{equation}\int_{C}\bar{z}dz\end{equation}
Where the integrand denotes the complex conjugate, and the path C is the path with label #2 on the image.

I did it without parametrization, that is, I've wrote the integrand as $x-iy$, and $\mathrm{d}z=\mathrm{d}x+i\,\mathrm{d}y$, and carried it out simply. My answer was $1-i$. However, I went to check in the solutions, and it was different. In the first line, the author expressed the integral in $\mathrm{d}y$ as $\int_{0}^{1}-iy\,\mathrm{d}y$, which does not make sense, since this integral comes from multiplying $(-iy)$ with $i\,\mathrm{d}y$. Here's the author's solution:
$$
\int_{C'} z^\ast\, \mathrm{d}z
= \int_0^1 (-iy) \, \mathrm{d}y + \int_0^1 (-i+x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= - \frac i 2 + \frac 1 2 - i
= \frac 1 2 - \frac 3 2 i
$$
Is that just a typo? That is the "answer" though, so its unlikely. What am I missing here? Seems pretty simple...
Thanks in advance.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Its a typo, the i at dy is missing.

Can you fill in the details behind “carried it out simply”? That would add a lot of helpful context.


In the first line, the author expressed the integral in $\, \mathrm{d}y$ as $\int_{0}^{1}-iydy$, which does not make sense, since this integral comes from multiplying $(-iy)$ with $i\, \mathrm{d}y$.

There's a typo; it should be
$$
\int_0^1 -yi \, i \, \mathrm{d}y
= 
\int_0^1 y \, \mathrm{d}y
= \frac 1 2
$$
This is a typo since the $\frac 1 2$ is still reflected in their answer.

To verify this is right, perhaps think of it differently: their first integral is
$$
I=\int_{\text{vertical line}} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z
$$
The vertical line ranges from $0$ to $i$, so $z$ ranges over $\{0+ti \mid t \in [0,1]\}$. Since these are the $z$ values on that line, then $\overline{z}$ ranges over $\{0-ti \mid t \in [0,1]\}$. (And this should make sense: recall the integral as a way of summing up changes in the values of a function.) So
$$
I = \int_0^1 \color{blue}{-yi} \cdot \, \mathrm{d}z
$$
Then, think about what a very small change in $z$ is along that same vertical line. A discrete change takes the form
$$
\Delta z = \Delta x + i \Delta y
$$
but, since $\Delta x = 0$ on that line (the real part of $z$ is constant), taking the limit of the discrete changes to get differentials, you get
$$
\mathrm{d}z = i \, \mathrm{d}y
$$
so
$$
I = \int_0^1 -yi \cdot \color{red}{i \, \mathrm{d}y}
\stackrel{-i^2=1} = \int_0^1 y \, \mathrm{d}y
$$

Long reply to a comment:

I agree, but the $1/2$ of the author comes from the integral $\int_0^1 x \, \mathrm{d}x$, not the $y$ integral. He actually carries it out as $\frac 1 2 i$, and gets a different answer. If we use the correct expression for the $y$-integral, the final answer would be $1-i$, different than the solution provided. Can we confidently say that the author's wrong?

Admittedly it did not occur to me to check the other integral in detail.
Yes, we can calculate the integral other ways and verify the answer. For the vertical line a suitable parameterization is
$$
\gamma(t) := ti \text{ for } t \in [0,1]
$$
In general, if going from $z_{\text{start}}$ to $z_{\text{end}}$ in a straight line, a suitable parameterization is
$$
\gamma_{\text{general}}(t) := (1-t) z_{\text{start}} + t z_{\text{end}} \text{ for } z \in [0,1]
$$
Then
$$
\int_{\text{vertical}} f \, \mathrm{d}z
= \int_0^1 f(\gamma(t)) \, \gamma'(t) \, \mathrm{d}t
$$
It becomes easy to calculate that, on the vertical line, you get $\frac 1 2$. Similarly, for the horizontal line, you could use the same style of argument as in my post proper or as above to conclude that
$$
\int_{\text{horizontal}} f \, \mathrm{d}z
= \int_0^1 \overline{t+i} \, \mathrm{d}t
= \frac 1 2 - i
$$
So indeed, the answer for the sum of the curves labeled $2$ is $1-i$. I suggest you verify this horizontal line calculation in other ways of your preference, e.g. the way I presented earlier would give
$$
\int_{\text{horizontal}} f(z) \, \mathrm{d}z
= \int_0^1 \color{blue}{\overline{x+i}} \, \color{red}{\mathrm{d}x}
= \int_0^1 (x-i) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac 1 2 - i
$$
since the top side uses numbers of the form $x+i$ for $x \in [0,1]$, and only the real parts of $z$ (the $x$'s) change.

I agree, but the 1/2 of the author comes from the integral $\int_{0}^{1}xdx$, not the y integral. He actually carries it out as $\frac{1}{2}i$, and gets a different answer. If we use the correct expression for the y-integral, the final answer would be 1-i, different than the solution provided. Can we confidently say that the author's wrong?

Due to length, I replied to this with an edit to the post itself
